# Flexbox sidebar with max-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to set max-width on the sidebar in my flexbox layout without affecting the content area (article)? Changing the max-width now also affects the content area. I want the current functionality, with the layout being responsive, but also setting a max-width on the sidebar.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bvcx/pen/PzXZxz)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="flex-container">

        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <article class="article">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ....</p>
        </article>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container > * {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.article {
  text-align: left;
}

.nav {
  background:#eee;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    flex:1 auto;
    -webkit-order:1;
    order:1;
  }

  .article {
    -webkit-flex:5 0px;
    flex:5 0px;
    -webkit-order:2;
    order:2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're telling both your `<nav>` and your `<article>` to grow as much as they can with this declaration:

```
.flex-container > * {
    flex: 1 100%;
}
```

You should define the default size of your `<nav>` element before the remaining space is distributed with `auto` instead of `100%`. The auto keyword means "look at my width or height property".

```
.flex-container > .nav {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Right there you're telling your `<nav>` to grow and shrink and never be wider than 300px (it's gonna be actually 330px because the padding isn't considered when doing this calculations)

**Edit:**

So in order to solve your problem I had to rewrite some code, here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daslaf/3c7nkcje/)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have tried your solution and it fixes the width problem, but breaks the responsive functionality. If you adjust the screen size before your solution you can see that the sidebar will get on top when the screen get smaller and fill the top screen. Is it possible to have a max width for the sidebar, but also keep the functionality with the sidebar filling the screen when going on top for smaller screens? Thanks again for helping out, much appreciated.

Comment: oh, my bad, I didn't realise what the @media query was doing, I'm gonna edit my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help. Everything works now :-)